# How do I automate mysqladmin, and mysql_secure_installation queries with .mylogin.cnf?

Tags: mysql, percona

I am looking at automating a couple things when installing MySQL to a new host using a Chef server. These include:

- mysqladmin -u root password {password_here}
- mysql_secure_installation

I've created a .mylogin.cnf file with two login-paths, admin (which is root user), and mysqluser (non root user).

My issues are that I can't get (or understand how) .mylogin.cnf to create the DB users and password; and I can't automate the mysql_secure_installation using --defaults-file=.mylogin.cnf (assuming that's how the --defaults-file works) even though it's not specifying a login-path. Initially I was running the mysql queries via command line to harden the service, but was told that mysql_secure_installation uses --no-defaults, and --defaults-file to automate this particular task, but haven't found much online about those arguments.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

The option `--defaults-file` is NOT used for setting/changing options in whichever tool you are running. This file is only used for specifying connection options (ie: host, username, socket, etc). For `mysql_secure_installation` specifically, you might try `--use-default` which, according to the manual, is used for unattended execution. In MySQL 5.7, a random root password is generated and printed in the error log. Simply grep this file for that password in your Chef script, then connect to MySQL and run whatever commands you need to create new users, dbs, etc. FYI, the generated root password is expired so when you connect, you have to change it first before you can do anything else.